Method to solve $0= \frac{x-1}{x} + f(x)$
Given an equation of the form:
$$0= \frac{x-1}{x} + f(x)$$
Knowing what $x_0$ makes $f(x_0)=0$, is it possible to determine when the full equation vanish? Are there particular techniques to study such problems?

Is it intentional there is an $a$ in your title, but not in your equation? In either case (since $a$ is in the denominator), $f(x_0)=0 \implies x_0=1$, irrespective of $a$.

@Ramashalanka mistake sorry, i'll edit

So, as in my previous comment, $f(x_0)=0 \implies 0=\frac{x_0-1}{x_0} + f(x_0) = \frac{x_0-1}{x_0} \implies x_0=1$.

If $x_0$ is not one does it mean that $\frac{x-1}{x}+f(x)$ is never zero right?

If, say, $f(x)=x-17$, then the only solution of $f(x_0)=0$ is $x_0=17$, but $${x-1\over x}+f(x)=0$$ has the solutions $x=8\pm\sqrt{65}$.

Knowing the solution(s) of $f(x_0)=0$ tells you very little about the solution(s) of $f(x)+((x-1)/x)=0$.

Makes sense @GerryMyerson. Are there any cases or techniques to try and get a solution?

If you really mean $0=\frac{x-1}x + f(x)$ for general $x$ then $f(x)=\frac{1-x}x$ and you know all about $f$. Do  you mean that equation for a specific $x$?

Yes, i actually have the function f(x), and i also managed to find its root. Now i need to find the roots of this new equation, for a generic x.

Got it. Gerry is right: we don't know the zeros of the new function, except that $x_0$ isn't one of them unless $x_0=1$. It depends on the form of $f$, not just its zeros.

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then you get a polynomial equation of degree $n+1$, and you can apply what you know about those. If $f(x)$ is a rational function, again you get a polynomial equation. If $f(x)$ is differentiable, then you have access to Newton's Method, to find decimal approximations of the solution(s). Why don't you tell us what your function is?

I was thinking that it was necessary, but i was hoping to not involve the function $f$ since it is tremendously nonlinear and i have few hopes of solving the problem

@GerryMyerson i didn't include it since i think it is not very helpful. It is the sum of a rational function and the product of a degree two polynomial with a trigonometric function of a function of x, i have already tried all the usual Calc methods and no one worked, that is why i was searching for more exotic/non standard alternatives that do not involve $f$ directly

Well, even a simple equation like $x-\cos x=0$ can only be solved numerically, so most likely that's all you can do for your problem.

Thank you @GerryMyerson, maybe i will try to taylor expand and solve the polynomial equation, i have a parameter that allow me to do that in my function

Well, first the function $f(x)$ must be compatible with the functional equation, let $g(x)=\frac{1-x}{x}$, then you want to solve $f(x)=g(x)$. We only need to know that there exists some $x_0$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, besides that any function $f$ could be taken as an input, for instance, let $f(x)=sin(x)$, we can see that there are quite a lot of solutions of $f(x)=g(x)$. The solutions are the intersections of both graphs.

but if we change f(x) to another function, say $f(x)=tan(x)$, we have another set of solutions that have (in my opinion) little to zero relation with the previous set of solutions, the graph is the following

I'm sure there must be some relation between these two sets of solutions but even if there is, it is fairly obscure.

Furthermore, not every $f(x)$ satisfies the equation, $f(x)=(1/2x)-1$ doesn't meet the function $g(x)$ at any point.
